# Matrix representation for point-wise operation

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have the following expression to implement in MATLAB:

```
(A*u).*(B*v)
```

Where `A` and `B` are matrices `N x N` and `u` and `v` column vectors `N x 1`.

For some reason, not really important at the moment, I want to represent it in the form `C(A,u,b)*v` for some matrix `N x N` originated by `A,u` and `B`.

How can I do that?

I tried to do something like using the following matrix

```
C = spdiags( A*u,0,N,N)*B
```

But it seems that the result is not really what I need.

Comment: can you be a little bit more specific regarding "the result is not really what I need"?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
C1 = bsxfun(@times, A*u,B) * v
```